# Can you map a dataset in tensorflow with 'keras.utils.to_categorical'?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

My dataset here is comprised of data in the following structure `[...x, y]` and I want to convert it to

`[...x], categorical([y])`

this is what I tried:

```
def map_sequence(sequence):
    return sequence[:-1], keras.utils.to_categorical(sequence[-1])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input_sequences)
dataset = dataset.map(map_sequence)
```

but I am getting an error as `sequence` does not actually have any data when mapping is executed.

how does one use `to_categorical` and `map()` together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `keras.utils.to_categorical` with `tf.one_hot` should do the trick.